# get opened chrome tabs from outside the browser

Tags: google-chrome

I need to check what tabs are opened in chrome, but I can't use the browser to do so. I need to do it from the cmd or from a python\c++ or any language that runs on the host computer, does anyone know how can I do it?

Thank you very much.